# Parse 3rd entry in declare result

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, declare

I have this:

> cd 31
>   /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/botch/botch-shell-overrides.sh

the above style output, is given by this command:

```
declare -F my_bash_func
```

How can I grab just the file name from that result? something like:

```
file=$(declare -F my_bash_func | grab_3rd_entry)
```

---

I have to use:

```
shopt -s extdebug
declare -F my_bash_func
shopt -u extdebug
```

but this doesn't work on MacOS:

```
shopt -s extdebug
declare -pf my_bash_func
shopt -u extdebug
```

the latter yields a weird error:

> declare: my_bash_func: not found

but using declare -F can find the function, so not sure why the `-pf` option doesn't work.

Comment: could you provide the output of `declare -pf my_bash_func` ?

Comment: I am on MacOS, has to be x-platform :(

Comment: I added details to answer your question

Comment: Ok, make that `declare -f my_bash_func` which works for bash (as you tagged your question) since version 2.03.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
file=$(declare -F my_bash_func | awk '{print $3}')
```

Or use bash built-ins, read it into an array:

```
func_info=( $(declare -F my_bash_func) )
file=${func_info[2]}
line_number=${func_info[1]}
```

But beware that `declare -F my_bash_func` output is not very friendly to parsers... If the file containing the function is sourced from a relative path, the `extdebug` output will just print a relative path (even if you're not in that directory anymore.) Furthermore, if the path has any spaces or unprintable characters, those will be preserved in the output (so "3rd field" is maybe not correct...)